# Block specific spam ip address to my websites

Tags: ip, web, blacklist

I have a website. It receives visits from about 50000 different ip addresses a day, I know it does not provide 100% protection, but I am thinking of doing an ip block operation on harmful ip addresses written on the internet.

Has anyone tried, practiced, or know anything about it?

I will get sample ip addresses from:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stamparm/ipsum/master/ipsum.txt

https://www.projecthoneypot.org/list_of_ips.php

https://www.maxmind.com/en/high-risk-ip-sample-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an IP address blacklist good practice to prevent website attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65/), [Is blacklisting IP addresses a waste of time?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82054/is-blacklisting-ip-addresses-a-waste-of-time), [Is it practical to pre-blacklist certain GeoIP regions?](/questions/124775), [Alternatives to blocking suspicious IP addresses?](/questions/137551/), [Is there any actual security benefit to restricting foreign IP addresses?](/questions/218098/)

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "IP blacklist". There is a lot of material out there on the topic and tons of tools.